# How to send JSON object message to ActiveMQ using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ. I need to send JSON object as message in it. I tried the following code:

```js
const stompit = require('stompit');

stompit.connect({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 61613
}, function (error, client) {
    const sendHeaders = {
        'destination': '/queue/newQ',
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    };
    const text = {
        name: "Sam",
        addr: {
            doorNo: 4,
            street: "4th Avenue",
            city: "New York"
        }
    }

    const frame = client.send(sendHeaders);
    frame.write(text);
    frame.end(); 
});
```

But its not working. Can anyone tell what is the problem here?

Comment: You should stringify the object and then parse it into json on other end.

Comment: @aaditya It works but is it the only way? I want to do it without conversion.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who run into this issue in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

STOMP is the [Simple (or Streaming) **Text** Orientated Messaging Protocol](https://stomp.github.io/). I emphasize *text* because your messages have to be in text. You can't send binary data like a JavaScript JSON variable. Use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) to turn the JSON variable into a string:

```js
const text = {
    name: "Sam",
    addr: {
        doorNo: 4,
        street: "4th Avenue",
        city: "New York"
    }
}

const frame = client.send(sendHeaders);
frame.write(JSON.stringify(text));
```

Then when you receive the message you can marshal that string back into an actual JSON object in whatever programming language you're using for the consumer. If you're using Javascript for the consumer you can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) to do this, e.g.

```js
var myJsonObj = JSON.parse(messageBody);
```